# Python pandas concat to multi index groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I'm new to pandas and I need help. I have two following reports which are quite simple.

```
$ cat test_report1
ID;TYPE;VAL
1;USD;5
2;EUR;10
3;PLN;3
$ cat test_report2
ID;TYPE;VAL
1;USD;5
2;EUR;10
3;PLN;1
```

Then I'm using concat to connect two reports with unique index:

```
A=pd.read_csv('test_report1', delimiter=';', index_col=False)
B=pd.read_csv('test_report2', delimiter=';', index_col=False)
C=pd.concat([A.set_index('ID'), B.set_index('ID')], axis=1, keys=['PRE','POST'])
print(C)
```

Which gives me following output:

```
          PRE     POST
         TYPE VAL TYPE VAL
ID
1         USD   5  USD   5
2         EUR  10  EUR  10
3         PLN   3  PLN   1
```

I find this pretty good but actually I would like rather to have:

```
     STATE TYPE VAL
ID
1         PRE  USD  5  
          POST USD  5
2         PRE  EUR  10
          POST EUR  10
3         PRE  PLN  3  
          POST PLN  1
```

Then it would be perfect with diff like:

```
         STATE TYPE VAL
ID
1         PRE  Nan  Nan
          POST Nan  Nan
2         PRE  Nan  Nan
          POST Nan  Nan
3         PRE  PLN  3  
          POST PLN  1
```

I know that this is doable but I'm stuck digging 3rd day to find a solution.

Comment: This might fix your problem: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and then sorting levels of `MultiIndex`:

```
df = (df.rename_axis(['STATE',None], axis=1)
        .stack(0)
        .sort_index(level=[0,1], ascending=[True, False])
        )
print (df)
         TYPE  VAL
ID STATE          
1  PRE    USD    5
   POST   USD    5
2  PRE    EUR   10
   POST   EUR   10
3  PRE    PLN    3
   POST   PLN    1
```